# How can I replace a dynamic library in Android in run time?

Tags: android, dynamic-library

I should to replace a dynamic library in Android . For example, any app uses `a.so`. I have not source code of a app, I download it from Google Market. I am sure that it uses a.so. But I need that my app using my own `a.so` in which I write with the same fucntions prototypes, constatnts and macros, I only change implementation of some functions and I compile it to take `a_my.so`. And how in this situation I can claim the app to use `a_my.so` instead `a.so`. And can I totaly replace `a.so` to `a_my.so` to  all app uses it?

**The main purpose**: it is to replace a system dynamic library (in particular, I want to do it with libGLESv20.so) to my own version of it.

Comment: You need to be clearer in the language you're using. If you do not have the source code to "your" app, then it's not "your" app. It's just an app you've managed to download from someone else. And without the source, you won't be able to re-compile it anyway. So even if we told you how to link a_my.so. The point would be moot, since you won't be able to recompile the app without the source. And yes, there are tools that allow the reverse-compiling of android applications, but those tools don't work flawlessly (except for the simplest of projects).

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I do not need to recompile apps. I need that the app uses another version of *.so instead the standard.

Comment: Hmm?? Assuming I only focus on the second part of your question. The answer is: "It depends". Android is built on top of embedded Linux and therefore inherits the security model of Linux. So if you want to change a shared object library at runtime, that is only possible if you have root access to that device, or if you can modify and compile your own source and sign that application (based on that shared object library) with your own key (and even then without root access, that second option would only affect your application, not any of the other applications written by others).

Comment: So the main question is. Will you have root access to that device? Or will you be compiling your own ROM? If not, don't count on your shared library being able to affect third party applications written by others. By design, the Android/Linux security model doesn't allow that.

Comment: But does any way exist to not replace fully *.so ( a.so to my a.so ) but only replace anywhere( I do not know where) only path which is used by apps to find *.so( before app uses path to a.so /lib/a.so and now it will use /home/dir/dir2/a.so).

Comment: I try to do it on virtual machine.